# Centos 6.7 broken Sudo

Tags: centos, sudo

After installing devtoolset 2, it appears my sudo command is broken.

```
readlink -f $(type -P sudo)

    /opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/sudo
```

I believe the commands I ran to install devtoolset2 included the following after installation: (taken from [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/381160/how-to-install-gcc-4-7-x-4-8-x-on-centos))

```
ln -s /opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/* /usr/local/bin/
sudo ln -s /opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/* /usr/local/bin/
```

Can anyone confirm if this would have broken sudo somehow and why? My theory is that the `ln -s` was too aggressive and has also aliased sudo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be fine.

What you've done is drop symlinks for items in `/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/` into `/usr/local/bin/`(the location of custom binaries). This is most likely in your PATH variable as well and is most likely prioritized higher (in case you wanted to override something manually). `sudo`, however, is usually located at `/usr/bin/sudo`.

If you do a `which -a sudo`, you should see all matches for `sudo`.

You should be able to access `sudo` by typing something like: `/usr/bin/sudo whoami`.

Comment: Thanks Paul :) The reason I noticed the problem is that vagrant was not finding various commands when trying to halt the machine. I *think* vagrant uses something other than an interactive shell to do this but not 100% sure.

Comment: No prob! Out of curiosity, did that end up working out for you okay?

Comment: I think it did but I did things too quickly to be sure and ```which -a sudo``` is only giving one sudo path now. I manually deleted the symlink to sudo which seems to have solved things. I will therefore accept your answer :). Its a vagrant box so can be rebuilt if necessary. Feel free to upvote my question :)